# Disable prompt on button click or create an official save button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a button outside of my gridview. Inside the gridview it has checkboxes, if i check one of them it saves the change upon button click in the database. However, when I click the button it displays a prompt "Are you sure, you want to leave this site, all changes will be lost?" Although the changes are actually saved in the backend.

Is there a way to remove this prompt or change the button to act like a "real" Save button?

```
<asp:gridview runat="server" id="MeasuresGrid"  autogeneratecolumns="False" cssclass="SelectionHeader" datakeynames="SubSectionId">
        //omitted
    </asp:gridview>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right">
            <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" text="Save" cssclass="hrsaSkingreybtn" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" CausesValidation="False" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please share code examples.

Comment: @HectorBarbossa updated

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the button's name and it's events? I only do these kinds of things in winforms, but typically, I'd do something like this:

```
btSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btSubmit_Click);
private void btSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureBoxes();            
        // send them... somewhere?                        
        MessageBox.Show("Options Saved!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Hope that helps.